# What are "SL_wptGlobTipTmp" and "SL_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp" cookies?

Tags: cookies

I am seeing these 2 cookies on most all websites in my chrome browser. 
Not in Safari and not in FireFox
Searching the web did not give me any information.   Lots of websites list the cookies in their privacy Policy with different reasons for creating them.
I can not find the origin of the cookie creation or reason for it
wonder if it is some kind of hack or ?

SL_wptGlobTipTmp

SL_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp

Comment: what is the question? what's the origin???

Comment: Figured it out ... its   js generated cookies from a  Chrome addon  ImTranslator: Translator, Dictionary, TTS

Answer (score 4):

Its js generated cookies from a Chrome addon ImTranslator.